# VB.net Copy folder from SharePoint to local computer

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, directoryinfo

I have written a VB.net application that backs up folders on our SharePoint 2007 server and puts a fresh copy of the files in their place. This application works perfectly on my Windows 7 computer, but when a colleague runs it on their Windows XP computer they get a number of errors. Try as I might to resolve them, I just cannot.

The first error is when I dim the DirectoryInfo variable. It connects to the WebDav folder on the SharePoint server. It seems that unless the user has manually mapped a drive to the UNC first (using their regular logon, no special credentials) they receive an Access Denied error. Since I have a workaround, this is not important, but if there is a solution it would help.

The second (and most important) error is that during the copy of files the Windows XP computer gets a "Delay Write Fail" error. Those files that receive this error are not properly backed up. This error does not even stop the program from running! Is there a way to resolve this?

```
Private Sub btnGo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click

    ' Dim all variables
    Dim i, countfiles As Integer
    Dim CompletedReports As New DirectoryInfo(GlobalVariables.ServerURL)
    Dim dNow As Date = Date.Today
    Dim friday As Date
    Dim friD, friM, friY, archiveFolder, archiveURL As String
    Dim FreshReports As New DirectoryInfo(GlobalVariables.ServerURL + "\Report Archive\Templates\")

    ' Prevent form from being closed while running
    btnDone.Enabled = False
    btnGo.Enabled = False
    btnRunSetup.Enabled = False
    Application.DoEvents()

    ' Calculate the archive date
    friday = dNow.AddDays(-(CInt((dNow.DayOfWeek + 1) Mod 7) + 1))
    friD = friday.Day
    friM = friday.Month
    friY = friday.Year
    If Len(friD) < 2 Then
        friD = "0" + friD
    End If
    If Len(friM) < 2 Then
        friM = "0" + friM
    End If
    archiveFolder = friY + "-" + friM + "-" + friD

    archiveURL = GlobalVariables.ServerURL + "\Report Archive\" + archiveFolder

    ' Count number of files in the current folder
    RecursiveCount(CompletedReports, i)

    ' Do the SharePoint Archive to the "Report Archive" folder
    countfiles = i
    PB_SharePointArchive.Maximum = i
    PB_SharePointArchive.Step = 1
    CopyDirectory(GlobalVariables.ServerURL, archiveURL, PB_SharePointArchive, LB_SharePointArchive_Name, False)
    LB_SharePointArchive_Name.Text = "Done!"

    ' If specified, do the Server Backup
    If GlobalVariables.RemoteBackup = True Then
        i = countfiles
        PB_RemoteBackup.Maximum = i
        PB_RemoteBackup.Step = 1
        CopyDirectory(GlobalVariables.ServerURL, GlobalVariables.RemotePath + archiveFolder, PB_RemoteBackup, LB_RemoteBackup_Name, False)
        LB_RemoteBackup_Name.Text = "Done!"
    End If

    ' If specified, do the Local Backup
    If GlobalVariables.LocalBackup = True Then
        i = countfiles
        PB_LocalBackup.Maximum = i
        PB_LocalBackup.Step = 1
        CopyDirectory(GlobalVariables.ServerURL, GlobalVariables.LocalPath + archiveFolder, PB_LocalBackup, LB_LocalBackup_Name, False)
        LB_LocalBackup_Name.Text = "Done!"
    End If

    ' Refresh the Reports
    i = 0
    RecursiveCount(FreshReports, i)
    PB_SharePointRefresh.Maximum = i
    PB_SharePointRefresh.Step = 1
    CopyDirectory(GlobalVariables.ServerURL + "\Report Archive\Templates\", GlobalVariables.ServerURL, PB_SharePointRefresh, LB_SharePointRefresh_Name, True)
    LB_SharePointRefresh_Name.Text = "Done!"

    ' All tasks done - unlock the close function
    btnDone.Enabled = True

End Sub


Private Sub CopyDirectory(ByVal sourceDir As String, ByVal destDir As String, ByRef progBar As ProgressBar, ByRef statusBox As Label, ByVal overwrite As Boolean)

    Dim prompt, retry

    If Not Directory.Exists(destDir) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDir)
    ElseIf Directory.Exists(destDir) And overwrite = False Then
        'MsgBox("The directory already exists!" + vbCrLf + "It looks like the backup has already been done for this week." + vbCrLf + "To continue, please delete the previous backup and restart the process", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "TSO Report Refresh")

        prompt = MsgBox("The directory already exists!" + vbCrLf + "It looks like the backup has already been done for this week." + vbCrLf + "Do you wish to delete the previous backup?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "TSO Report Refresh")
        If prompt = vbYes Then
            DeleteDirectory(destDir)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDir)
        Else
            MsgBox("You have chosen not to delete the previous backup. Backup cannot continue." + vbCrLf + "To continue, please delete the previous backup and restart the process", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "TSO Report Refresh")
        End If
    End If

    For Each strEntry As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir)
        Dim fileNew As FileInfo
        fileNew = New FileInfo(strEntry)

        If fileNew.Exists Then
            retry = 3
            statusBox.Text = "Current File: " + fileNew.Name
            Application.DoEvents()
            While retry > 0
                Try
                    fileNew.CopyTo(destDir & "\" & fileNew.Name, True)
                    retry = 0
                    progBar.PerformStep()
                    Application.DoEvents()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    retry = retry - 1
                    If retry = 0 Then
                        MsgBox("A file has failed to copy after three attempts. The application will now close." + vbCrLf + fileNew.Name, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "TSO Report Refresh")
                        End
                    End If
                    'Debug.Print("Retrying file " + fileNew.Name + " for the " + (3 - retry) + " time...")
                End Try
            End While
        End If
    Next

    For Each strEntry As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir)
        If Path.GetFileName(strEntry) = "Report Archive" Or Path.GetFileName(strEntry) = "Forms" Then
            'Do Nothing!
        Else
            Dim strDest As String = Path.Combine(destDir, Path.GetFileName(strEntry))
            CopyDirectory(strEntry, strDest, progBar, statusBox, overwrite)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It'd probably help us to help you if you tried to isolate the problem a bit more. If you can reduce this down to a small function with just the copy command in it and all the rest of the application removed. You may find along the way that you discover what the problem is.

Comment: About the "Delay Write Fail" error: This points usually to a hardware problem. For example, USB/SATA cable disconnected or the communication with the device otherwise lost. You can test your application on other Windows XP machine to find out whether it affects just one particular computer. Because Windows flush the device buffers asynchronously (if write-behind is on) to improve performance, errors are reported later and not when your code writes to a file. You can monitor these errors in the event log.

Comment: @FerdinandPrantl I have tried on another Win XP machine with same result. It's not the same files everytime that get this error, but some files in the list do. Again, everything works perfectly on a Win7 machine.

Derek Tomes I will try to deconstruct the app a bit more to troubleshoot, but I do not have constant access to a Win XP machine to test. I will let you know how I go.